# Spring How to map list of custom pojo

Tags: spring

In my application.yml file, I want to define a list of rules.

```
rules:
   - name: abc
     value: something
   - name: edf
     value: something
```

Then I want to define a service like this

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   public MyService(@Value("${rules}") List<Rule> rules) {
   }
}
```

For the Rule pojo, it's like this.

```
public class Rule {
   public String name, value;
}
```

Currently, I'm facing these errors.

1. If I leave rules empty, it throws `can't convert String to List<Rule>`

   rules: []
2. If I keep the values, it throws `could not resolve placeholder 'rules'`

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

From Spring docs, I found this.

> Using the @Value("${property}") annotation to inject configuration
>   properties can sometimes be cumbersome, especially if you are working
>   with multiple properties or your data is hierarchical in nature.
>   Spring Boot provides an alternative method of working with properties
>   that lets strongly typed beans govern and validate the configuration
>   of your application

Link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

At the end, I have to introduce another class.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="rules")
public class Rules {
   public List<Rule> list;
}
```

Then I autowire it in `MyService`.